# What specific toxins are formed during deep frying? And how (chemically) do they attack the body cells?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, chemical-biology

From what I understand, deep frying causes the oxidation of lipids into advanced lipid oxidation products. When these are consumed and metabolized by the body, they release ROS or free radicals which damage DNA and other cellular components, paving the way for age related decline, chronic inflammation and terminal illnesses such as cancer, Alzheimer's etc.

What are the names of some of these carcinogens from frying?

Here's an arbitrary example: Lets say we had some chicken fingers and french fries. What specific carcinogens are formed when the chicken and potato are kept in hot oil for a long period of time?

And what are the biochemical mechanisms by which they harm the body?

Comment: This question could only be answered after someone finishes a PhD and a postdoc on this topic. Believe it or not it might take 7-8 years to find answers to those questions and even more.